# Why is the compiler not throwing error when Assigning object of sub class to parent reference

Tags: java, object, inheritance

```
class Base {
    public void show() {
        System.out.println("Base class show() method called");
    }
}

class Derived extends Base {
    public void show() {
        System.out.println("Derived class show () method called");
    }
}

public class Main {
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Base b = new Derived();//why is java allowing me to create an object of child class
    b.show();              //how can the Base class hold and use the reference of child
    }                              
}
```

What if I create an new method in the child class ??
Will the parent class still be able to access the new method ??

```
class Derived extends Base {
    public void show() {
        System.out.println("Derived class show () method called");
    }
    public void poo() {
        System.out.println("take a poo");
    }
}

public class Main {
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Base b = new Derived();
    b.show();   
        b.poo(); 
    }                              
}
```

Why is java allowing me to assign a reference of child to base class and not throwing any warnings or errors.

Comment: because that is one of the main features of Object Oriented programming - since `Derived` is extending `Base`, it has all members of `Base` (and eventually some more), so it can be used as `Base`. (Maybe better example `Cat` extends `Animal` , so I can assign an instance of `Cat` to a variable of type `Animal` - a `Cat` is an `Animal` (and some more specific characteristics)

Comment: "Why is java allowing me to assign a reference of child to base class"  Because you're allowed to do this in Java.

Comment: Your final example won't compile, you cannot call `b.poo();` via `Base b`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is called [polymorphism](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polymorphism_(computer_science)). Any derived class can necessarily be considered an instance of a parent class (without explicit casting).

The methods you can call and fields you can access depend on the static type of the object. In the case of `Base b = new Derived();`, the static type of `b` is `Base`, so you can only call methods visible on `Base`. New methods defined in `Derived` cannot be used.

Comment: I'm getting how it can be done / the features java is providing for this approach.Is there a reason why programmers generally use this approach.

Comment: cant they use the Derived reference instead of using the base class reference. I mean Isn't it restricting the access only to the variables or methods available in base class ?